# How to manage a Mongo database in XCode with CoreData using RestKit

Tags: ios, xcode, mongodb, core-data, restkit

I'm using RestKit with CoreData trying to manage a Mongo database. The JSON received by the Rest Service is like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$id": "511bc374a8af9ba27b597633"
    },
    "name": "javi",
    "email": "javi@email123",
    "passwordSHA1": 1234,
    "nationality": "Brasil",
    "gender": 0,
    "borndate": 1360686828,
    "filephoto_id": 1234567,
    "pi_selected": 1,
    "profile_interest": [{
        "name": "perfil prueba1",
        "tourism": ["Cinemas", "Concerts"],
        "leisure": ["NightLife", "Bars"],
        "foodtype": ["African", "American"]
    }, {
        "name": "perfil prueba2",
        "tourism": ["Theathers", "Concerts"],
        "leisure": ["NightLife", "Bars"],
        "foodtype": ["African", "American"]
    }],
    "accesibility": ["Blind", "Deaf"],
    "plans": [{
        "name": "plan prueba 1",
        "location_ids": [10001, 10002, 10003]
    }, {
        "name": "plan prueba 2",
        "locations_ids": [10002, 10003, 10004]
    }]
}
```

I have two questions:

1. How can I manage this information in Coredata (and if you know any tutorial that explain this). By now, I can fill only "User" Table when i call the Rest Service (not profile interest, accessibility and plans) , but i would like to  fill the other tables with the same calling.
2. Do I may to add an atribute "id" in the "User" table? (how can i get it with the mapping provider if I received the JSON showed above?